# Wifi Profile Missing on Debian

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

My default Wifi Profile is missing on Debian.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P7mm.png

What is the easiest way to restore the default wifi profile?

Regarding driver installation I found on:

https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=151517

"Installing the newest kernel from backports did the trick."

How would I do that?

Running `lspci -nn`:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing the correct driver? What is your WiFi card model? Use `lspci -nn` and use the PCI code (looks like `[12ab:34cd]`) to search for a driver.

Comment: It is a RTL8821CE controller.

Comment: Please add that information to the question - it is essential. I got it working under Debian using [this driver](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce). There is a section regarding a compiling howto for debian on the page.